# lapply to run to run two anonymous functions simultaneously

Tags: r, dplyr, survey

I have data such as this. I am using the `survey` package to produce the `MEAN`, `SE` and `FREQ` of each variables in the vector named vars.

```
library(survey)

df <- data.frame(sex = c('F', 'M', NA, 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F'),
                 married = c(1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1),
                 pens = c(0, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 0, 0),
                 weight = c(1.12, 0.55, 1.1, 0.6, 0.23, 0.23, 0.66, 0.67))


vars <- c("sex","married","pens")
```

This is my survey design:

```
design <- svydesign(ids=~1, data=df, weights=~weight)
```

I am using lapply to find the means:

```
lapply(vars, function(x) 
    svymean(as.formula(paste0('~interaction(', x, ')')), design, na.rm = T))
```

I am using lapply to find the freqs:

```
lapply(vars, function(x) 
    svytable(as.formula(paste0('~interaction(', x, ')')), design))
```

**Is there a way to run lapply over these two functions as the same tine? I would like my output to look like this:**

```
                   mean     SE     freq
interaction(sex)F 0.60345 0.2067    2.45
interaction(sex)M 0.39655 0.2067    1.61
```

I tried:

```
lapply(vars, function(x) 
  svymean(as.formula(paste0('~interaction(', x, ')')),
  svytable(as.formula(paste0('~interaction(', x, ')')), design)))
```

Comment: Just write your anonymous function to return both results in a list?

Comment: @Dason please suggest ways to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would just be to have the function return both results in a list. But also honestly I find it better if things are getting complicated to create the function outside of the lapply.  So this is what I would probably do:

```
myfun <- function(x){
  means <- svymean(as.formula(paste0('~interaction(', x, ')')), design, na.rm = T)
  table <- svytable(as.formula(paste0('~interaction(', x, ')')), design)
  results <- list(svymean = means, svytable = table)
  return(results)
}

lapply(vars, myfun)
```

You obviously could just do this as an anonymous function like...

```
lapply(vars, function(x){
      means <- svymean(as.formula(paste0('~interaction(', x, ')')), design, na.rm = T)
      table <- svytable(as.formula(paste0('~interaction(', x, ')')), design)
      results <- list(svymean = means, svytable = table)
      return(results)
    })
```

You don't necessarily even need to store the intermediate results

```
lapply(vars, function(x){
      list(svymean = svymean(as.formula(paste0('~interaction(', x, ')')), design, na.rm = T), svytable = svytable(as.formula(paste0('~interaction(', x, ')')), design))})
```

But hopefully you'll agree that isn't pretty.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful, I wonder if there is a way to get those result  in the format I mentioned in my question? I need to ultimately export this as a df for processing... and this output is too messy...

Comment: I don't use the svy**** functions so honestly I'm not too familiar with what they produce. I was just literally copying what you had in your questions and putting the results together in a list as that is what you were requesting - both results at the same time.  If you find a way to use svymeans and svytable and select the output from them such that they just give the number you want (I'm guessing the issue is that they return objects with lots of numbers) then you could modify this to be much more to your liking.

Answer (score 2):

This puts the freq and the means on the same row:

```r
lapply(vars, function(x){
       out <-data.frame(eval(bquote(svymean(~interaction(.(as.name(x))), design, na.rm = T))))
       table <- eval(bquote(svytable(~.(as.name(x)),design)))
       out$freq <- table
       out 
       })
```